# When to register OP_WRITE

Tags: java, design-patterns, nio, nonblocking, reactor

I use NIO with reactor pattern to connect a server to a client. My codes are as follows:
Server side codes, in the block of  `if(selectionKey.isWritable){} :`

```
public void isWritable(SelectionKey selectionKey) throws Exception {

        SocketChannel socketChannel =
                (SocketChannel) selectionKey.channel();

        Integer myInteger = (Integer) selectionKey.attachment();

        if (myInteger == null){
            int myJob = jobFacade.isAnyJob(socketChannel, 100 /*deadline*/);
            if (myJob > 0){

                ByteBuffer inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap("available\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
                socketChannel.write(inputBuffer);
                myInteger = myJob;
                socketChannel.register(
                        selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE, myInteger);

            }else if (myJob == -1){

                ByteBuffer inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap("unavailable\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
                socketChannel.write(inputBuffer);
                socketChannel.close();

                UnsupportedOperationException un = new UnsupportedOperationException();
                throw un;

            }else if (myJob == -2){

                ByteBuffer inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap("pending\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
                inputBuffer.flip();
                socketChannel.write(inputBuffer);
                myInteger = null;
                socketChannel.register(
                        selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE, myInteger);

            }
//            is there any new job to do?
        }else{

            int myInt = myInteger.intValue();

            if ( myInt > 0 ){

                long startRange = jobFacade.findByID(myInt);
                sendTextFile(startRange, Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("workUnit")),
                             properties.getProperty("textPath"), socketChannel);
                myInteger = -3;
                socketChannel.register(
                        selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE, myInteger);

            }else if (myInt == -3){

                sendAlgorithmFile(socketChannel, properties.getProperty("algorithmPath"));
                myInteger = -4;
                socketChannel.register(
                        selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE, myInteger);
//                send algorithm file

            }else if (myInt == -4){
                int isOK = jobFacade.isAccepted(socketChannel.socket().getInetAddress().toString(),
                                                Long.parseLong(properties.getProperty("deadline")));
                if(isOK == -1){

                    ByteBuffer inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap("notaccepted\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    socketChannel.write(inputBuffer);
                    myInteger = null;
                    socketChannel.register(
                            selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE, myInteger);
                }else {

                    ByteBuffer inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap("accepted\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    socketChannel.write(inputBuffer);
                    myInteger = isOK;
                    socketChannel.register(
                            selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ, myInteger);
                }
//                send "accepted" or "not accepted"
            }
        }
    }
```

It is no need to know what my methods in each block do except that these methods generate a number with this order at first. 1)myInteger=null, 2) myInteger > 0, 3) myInteger = -3, 4) myInteger = -4
In this order, OP-WRITE will register consecutively for four times. And this part is so important. So lets see my Client side code and then I will tell you my problem:

```
BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            sentence = inFromServer.readLine();
            System.out.println("Response from Server : " + sentence);


            if (sentence.equals("available")){

                BufferedReader inFromServer1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                while ((sentence = inFromServer1.readLine()) != null) {
                     myJob = myJob + sentence ;
                }


inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                String acception = inFromServer.readLine();
                if (acception.equals("accepted")){

                    File file = new File("account.json");
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
                    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                    OutputStream outputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                    int count;
                    try {
                        while ((count = inputStream.read(bytes)) > 0){
                            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, count);
                        }
                        outputStream.close();
                        inputStream.close();

                    }catch (IOException io){}

                    continue;

                }else if (acception.equals("notaccepted")){

                    continue;

                }
```

Now, my problem is that when I run my server and then my client, my server will run without waiting for my client to get input stream. First, the client get "available" but when the second getInputStream will be reached in client, the server paced all the phase of OP-WRITE registering and wait for client to get streams of data (As I defined in my code).
Actually, my server do its job well. It will pass all the stages in required order. But the problem is that sending and receiving data is not synchronous. 
I do not know what my problem is. But I guess when I register OP-WRITE consecutively, it means that my server did not send all bytes of data, so just the first getInputStream will get the data.
On the other hand, I need this order to run my program. So, Is there any Idea?

Comment: You need to provide the LEAST amount of code that illustrates your problem.

Comment: The code is as hard to understand as the explanation. There is a loop on the server but not on the client. So why do you need the server loop? How do you synchronize so you don't clear something the server wrote?

Comment: I have to use reactor pattern with non blocking NIO. Here when I send sth to my client, the first time my client receives complete message, but the second time, the client can find nothing in buffer. There is no difference if I replace the second part of client and server side code with the first ones and vice versa. I think I might misunderstand non blocking NIO or I cannot use buffers in its right way!

Comment: Yeah, the second part of client side code must have loop. But with or without loop, the client can find nothing in buffer, in this position. If I put the second part of each code in the first position, with loop, the client can read "Account.class" correctly. But again the second message is unavailable for the client.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will help you clarify the problem before thinking about patterns:

You have one thread/process that passes a message asking another thread/ process to act upon the message.

The receiver needs to read the message and maybe start some child threads of its own to perform that work because it can receive other requests.

It would be nice to tell the sender that an acknowledgment that the request was received.

It seems necessary that the message passing is protected. Because if another requests comes in while you are reading you could end up processing garbage.

You can configure nio to have several readers and just one writer, just read one portion of a buffer, etc. Check the how-tos, api docs. It is plenty powerful

Comment: You can't 'configure NIO' to have any readers or wrtiters. You do the reading and writing yourself, however you like. Nothing here that answers the actual question.

Comment: I suggest you read first: MappedByteBuffer out = new RandomAccessFile("howtodoinjava.dat", "rw") I s read /wirte. Then Yo can also do MappedByteBuffer out = new RandomAccessFile("howtodoinjava.dat", "r") read only

Comment: So yes , you can do read  and read writes only. The question at point is to help more in the homework but...

Comment: I haven't said you can't 'do read and read writes only', by which I assume you mean 'reads or writes only'. *Of course* you can. What I said is that this is not a 'configuration' step: it is just programming, and it has nothing to do with the question. The actual statement you made is meaningless, and your answer doesn't identify the actual problem.

Comment: Everyone, thanks for taking your time to solve my problem 

Comment: @Sarah Solve it how? If you're not going to identify the solution, your question is just a waste of space and should be deleted.

Comment: @EJP: If I knew how to solve my problem, I have never asked any questions!!!!! Here, the best answer is "efektivte"'s. And I checked it. But it is not my fault if no one knows the solution for this problem. If you are professional, you will ask me some questions to make my question clear for yourself and then you can solve my problem. So, is it my fault?

Answer (score 0):

I find out my problem. There is no problem with my code. OP_WRITE can be registered any time with any order. The most important thing is to write to buffer and read from socket correctly.
Actually, when I send something for the second time to my client, I did not clear the buffer. In this case I found it, and correct it. 
But when I send some characters to my client and then want to send a file, because in my client side I have a loop to get all characters, the content if the file is gotten by the same loop.
The question here is that how I can make them separate?

Answer (score -1):

> exactly after sending a message

There is no such thing as a message in TCP. It is a byte stream. Two writes at the sender are very likely to by read by one read at the receiver. If you want messages you have to implement them yourself, with count words, terminators, STX/ETX, XML, etc.

Comment: I changed my code. In server side I have Socketchanne while in client side I have socket. I check my codes, one by one in simple communication. Means for example my server just send a file to my client and everything works well. But when I start writing and reading on channel conservatively, the problem will appear. For example, first, the server send "available" then I register OP-WRITE again and server send some characters. But sending and receiving data is not synchronous. Means my server send "available" and some characters, while my client just received "available"!!!!!